# Make some docker run arguments required

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, containers

Is there a way I can enforce my image to require some `docker run` arguments without which the image won't work?

Let say my image requires access to `/dev/pigpio`, I'm looking for something like:

```
docker run myimage
docker: Error myimage requires access to pigpio device
```

Or maybe there is a way to embed parameters inside an image?

Like when someone do `docker run myimage`, `--device /dev/pigpio` is implied?

Basically I'm just looking for a way to make things plug and play.

Comment: Use docker-compose and encode this information into the compose file, then have your users run `docker-compose up`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@johnharris85 suggests one way for you to control the usage of the image.

Others include providing a shell script that runs it and documentation.

Unfortunately, none of these prohibits someone pulling your container image and running it without the flag.

A better option that I think is more "Docker" would be to have your container image check for these requirements. Check for the existence of the device that you require, and, if the device exists, possibly then check that it exhibits some expected behavior.

This gives your image the possibility to respond with a more precise error message  `"/dev/pigpio exists but it doesn't ... "`

It's an interesting suggestion to provide these controls on `docker run ...` itself but I suspect the diversity of options that are permitted means that delegating this to the container's process makes most sense.